# Change path for default SQL Server trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I change the path for the default trace in SQL Server? Can this be done with SQL Management Studio or do I have to use sp_configure

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default Trace is located in the same folder as the SQL Server Error Log.

In order to move the location of the default trace, you also need to move the SQL Server Error Log.